# How to connect RStudio in Azure Databricks to Delta Lake

Tags: rstudio, sparkr, azure-databricks, delta-lake

[image][image]Is there a way to connect RStudio that is on Azure Databricks Cluster to Delta Lake / Delta tables? (read and write mode would be awesome).

In RStudio on cluster I tried to set up the path to home directory:

```
- dbfs:/mnt/20_silver/
- ~dbfs:/mnt/20_silver/
- ~/mnt/20_silver/
- /mnt/20_silver/
```

But still didn`t succeed. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

To make a Spark connection you can run the following code in the RStudio Ui:

```
SparkR::sparkR.session() /
library(sparklyr)  /
sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")  /
```

It will work unless you have any ACLS on the file system.

Comment: If you have ACLS you will get the following error: @In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sparklyr/java//sparklyr-2.4-2.11.jar', reason 'Permission denied'

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? or are you still looking for an answer.

Comment: It turned out to be more complex: even if i fix the ACL, do i want all the R users to get access to all the Delta lake? If you have any experience/ ideas please share.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
spark_read_delta(sc, path, name = NULL, version = NULL,
timestamp = NULL, options = list(), repartition = 0,
memory = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE, ...)
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/1.0.5/topics/spark_read_delta